# External JavaScript file, HTML5, "Attribute scr not allowed on element script at this point."

Tags: javascript, html

Been a while I worked on new projects, when trying to start with blank html5 file, my external javascript file is not loaded, w3c validator says:

"Attribute scr not allowed on element script at this point."

I use  snippet.

my entire file looks like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Book Example</title>
   <script scr="./main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Any Idea?
I tried with single quotes, adding type, and putting script in body.

Comment: Substitute `src` for `scr`

Comment: OMG, haha, thank you very much:)

Comment: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/yimuwcjquJA/maxresdefault.jpg